# How do Juliette and Nick only have one bedroom?

Tags: grimm

Right through *Grimm* season two, I was thoroughly confused by Nick sleeping on the couch. They have quite a large house, so how is there room for only one (relatively small) bedroom upstairs?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question. After 38 years of (a pretty darn good) marriage, sleeping on the couch isn't at all unusual. Our current house has two unoccupied bedrooms other than the master bedroom. The previous house also had two unoccupied edrooms plus one for our daughter. Before that, a single extra bedroom; and before that... hmmm... at least three spares. Yet the couch has always been the preferred alternative whenever either of us sleeps anywhere but the master bedroom, with only rare occasions, e.g., the flu, when quiet isolation and bed rest are desired that a spare bedroom

Answer (score 11):

This is a common TV Trope known as [Exiled to the Couch](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ExiledToTheCouch). The man has to sleep on an uncomfortable couch instead of a bed. Even when circumstances should allow him to sleep in another available bed.

[The real life house](http://www.zillow.com/homedetails/805-NE-Prescott-St-Portland-OR-97211/53879333_zpid/) that was used in the Pilot which Nick and Juliette supposedly live in has 4 bedrooms.

Comment: And in the past two episodes, we've seen a second bedroom get used by a guest

Comment: Great jpb on finding the actually house size.

Answer (score 3):

There are actually 2 bedrooms and 2 bathrooms upstairs in Nick and Juliette's home. Juliette explained this to Kenneth in Season 4. Also, TRUBLE stayed in the second bedroom during her stay with Nick and Juliette in Seasons 3 & 4.

Comment: Can you add some quotes from the show to support this?

Comment: There aren't any need for quotations. If you watched the show, you know Truble stayed downstairs in her own room during that time. This is the same room one of Nick's books is found in later.

Answer (score 0):

There are different options (why he sleeps on the coach)

1. The Grimm wanted to sleep on the couch because a different bed would make it(problems with girlfriend) real.
2. They don't have a bed in the other room(s) or the rooms are offices/ full with boxes.

There are two bedrooms and two baths in the first floor. Nothing more.
The ground floor has kitchen with door, garage with door, "sitting room"/room with THE coach, PC (later) and perhaps more.

I want to thank the real house (4 bedrooms) and episode thing. I search for a room number.