# How could he sell the house?

Tags: grimm

In *Grimm* [Lost Boys (S5E3)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4903278/?ref_=ttep_ep3),

> Nick sells the house that he lives in.

However, as we learn when Juliette is having memory issues, it is Juliette's house, and Nick moved in with her.  At the time of her

> "death"

they are not married, and even if they had been,

> her death has not been widely disclosed,

so he would not have any form of ownership, much less sole ownership.  So how does he manage to do it?

Comment: Tv-magic OFC! He had to get the money from somwhere to buy all the room he has in the latest episode. Sooo. hokus-pokus! He sold the house that isnt his to sell to get the cash. We cant have our hero go rob a bank or trip over a suitcase full of cash now can we? For all we know Juliette had a will where she left it all to Nick. All of this happened off-screen!!

Comment: @Cherubel To that point, wouldn't it have been just as easy to have him buy the other place and leave the house empty?  He appears have money, since he was able to buy the acreage where he kept the trailer.  Also, for Juliette to have a will that left him the house, she would have to be publicly dead, which she was not, since the scene was cleaned up.  No body = no death.

Comment: Probably in the background where we don't see it he went through tenancy survivorship, and claimed the property as his own so he was able to sell it. That's all part of why all (or mostly all) real estate transactions require a lawyer. To assure properties are actually clear to sell. We don't see any of that process going on.

Comment: @Escoce Right, but again, legally Juliette is not dead.  At best, she is missing, and a person must be missing for 7 years before being declared dead.  If you can find a legal explanation for why the live-in boyfriend of a person who has been missing for less than 6 months is able to sell the missing person's house, I will accept as answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, in the cited episode *Lost Boys,* when Adalind asks Nick how long he has lived in the house he says:

> About uh six and a half years. I never thought I'd be here forever, but I didn't know anything about being a Grimm **when I bought it.**

In *The Good Shepherd* Juliette offers to move out, which doesn't make a lot of sense if it is her home.

In *Season of the Hexenbiest* Nick gets fed up with Juliette and *does* move out, instead of continuing to sleep on the coach (even though they have a spare bedroom [How do Juliette and Nick only have one bedroom?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56310/how-do-juliette-and-nick-only-have-one-bedroom))

Let's say the writers might have screwed up and it *is* Juliette's house.

In Oregon, when it comes to [unmarried couples and property](http://www.mckinleyirvin-oregon.com/Family-Law-Blog/2015/January/The-Rights-of-Unmarried-Couples-in-Oregon.aspx).

> - Each partner is entitled to their own property and debts unless they have been deliberately combined
> - A written agreement to share assets overcomes the legal presumption of independent property
> - Jointly owned property is owned in equal parts by each partner

It is possible that Nick and Juliette had a written agreement allowing them to share assets. This would enable Nick to be able to sell the home.

Also, even though they have lived together for presumably 6.5 or more years, there is no common law marriage in Oregon.

Comment: Good answer, though I am positive that when Juliette was regaining her memories near the end of season 2 it is definitely her house, as there are memories of him moving in.  I will try to find the episode tonight.

Comment: @DaveJohnson that was *Volcanalis.* So there is a lack of continuity between episode and the episode where Nick says he bought it.